# Random shuffle of array, but keep diagonal fixed

Tags: python, numpy, random, shuffle

I have defined an array that looks like this:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,1,5], [6,7,1]])
```

I would like to randomly shuffle it, but keep the 1's in the diagonal fixed. When I do

```
B = [0,1,2]
np.random.shuffle(B)
```

all elements are shuffled, including the 1's in the diagonal.

Does anyone know a solution to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use [`masking`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
m = ~np.eye(len(A), dtype=bool) # mask of non-diagonal elements

# Extract non-diagonal elements as a new array and shuffle in-place
Am = A[m]
np.random.shuffle(Am)

# Assign back the shuffled values into non-diag positions of input
A[m] = Am
```

Another way would be to generate the flattened indices and then shuffle and assign -

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(m)
A.flat[idx] = A.flat[np.random.permutation(idx)]
```